# How to approve spending limit on Metamask or Etherscan to complete a swap on Balancer Exchange?

Tags: erc-20, metamask, etherscan, defi

Hope you can help unstick this transaction...

I recently used Balancer Exchange to swap USDC for KYL via Metamask. The transaction shows as successful on Etherscan but my Metamask balance has not updated. I didn't receive any popup from Metamask for further action but it appears I need to approve my spending limit to release my USDC.

How can I do this please??

And in future is there a way to pre-approve spending limits on Metamask?

Comment: Maybe you just need switch to the Assets tab in Metamask, click on "Add Token" and add USDC, so that you can see your USDC balance. Usually approve gets called before another contract can interact with your ERC20 tokens (not after). Could you provide the tx hash?